# Set image as content of reminder in windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, reminders

there is way to set a image as content or title of reminder in windows phone 8 like toast notification and can i customize the reminder UI like toast notification

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No (sorry) - there is no way to customize either the content (other than the text) or the UI itself.